# Appropriate Format to store dataset in github

Tags: git, github, dataset

I have around 2000 files in the dataset. What is the correct format to upload it to Github repository, as Github prompts me I can't upload folder with more than 100 files? What is a standard practice utilized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case:

- make multiple commits (all with less than 100 files)
- push each commits.

That could be scripts, especially if your fileset has a simple structure.